# Properties on Datomic ref relationships

Tags: datomic

I'm trying to model a schema where a `list` can have many `items` and each `item` can belong to many `lists`. It's clear to me that I can have a `:list/items` ref type to model the relationship, but I'd like to also have a `rank` attribute which determines an item's position in each list where it exists. How might one do such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only answer I have - assuming that positioning is list dependent - is that you need to add an indirecting entity with a rank attribute. This isn't very pleasant. It would be nice if a many relation could be ordered, as this use case would simplify substantially.

Answer (score 1):

[Heterogenous tuples](https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/schema.html#heterogeneous-tuples), added in June 2019, are a new modelling option here.

An attribute value, i.e. the `v` in the `eavto` 5-tuple, can now itself be a tuple. This is a clojure vector of max length 8.

Official [blog post](https://blog.datomic.com/2019/06/tuples-and-database-predicates.html) announcement.

Discussion of the release on [twitter](https://twitter.com/datomic_team/status/1144615294608039937).

Note the example in the docs above uses

```clj
:db/tupleTypes [:db.type/long :db.type/long]
```

which is a little strange as the point is *hetero*genous tuples, so in the case of the OP this would be:

```clj
{:db/ident       :list/item
 :db/valueType   :db.type/tuple
 :db/tupleTypes  [:db.type/ref :db.type/long] ; ref to item, rank
 :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/many}
```

Or you could use a value type instead of a ref for item, if that works for you.

To use this in datalog, you can use the [tuple](https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/query.html#tuple) and [untuple](https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/query.html#untuple) functions.

Comment: I did not check but I suppose reverse relation will not work in such case since VAET will not be available when value type is :db.type/tuple instead of :db.type/ref. https://docs.datomic.com/pro/query/indexes.html#VAET