# How to implement sorted to-many relationships in Datomic?

Tags: clojure, database-schema, datomic

There is no out-of-the-box schema feature in Datomic for sorting child entities in a to-many relationship, yet this is a very common requirement. Googling has uncovered a few solutions so I wanted to inventory the variations of requirements and solutions here and hope for comments from the community.

**Possible Requirements**

- R1: small numbers (N) of child entities (not sure what the small/large
  threshold should be)
- R2: large numbers of child entities
- R3: single-parent children
- R4: multi-parent children
- R5: recursive children i.e. trees stored in Datomic

My particular use case is R1 + R3 + R5 which I suspect is pretty common but I wanted to enumerate as many as possible so that this might become a useful reference for others in future.

**Solutions**

- S1: nested component entities with a "position" attribute e.g. [Datofu](https://github.com/vvvvalvalval/datofu#implementing-ordered-to-many-relationships-with-an-array-data-structure)
- S2: add a custom "position" attribute to every child as described [using transactor fns here](http://augustl.com/blog/2013/ordering_cardinality_many_in_datomic/) and in [this post](https://juxt.pro/blog/posts/datascript-dom.html)
- S3: linked list using a "next" attribute on every child entity as implemented in [datomic-linklist](https://github.com/dwhjames/datomic-linklist)
- S4: separate wrapper entities representing edges as [described in this post](http://jmhofer.johoop.de/datomic/2012/08/18/linked-lists-in-datomic.html)

**Problems**

Each solution seems to have challenges. The ones I can think of are:

- P1: maintaining constant time operations for insert, delete or move operations. There have been suggestions to use fractional numbers for "position" values to avoid having to update all children when re-ordering
- P2: supporting multiple parent relationships with ordering
- P3: complexity of maintaining the positions or edges that store the order as ordering or membership changes.
- P4: changes to a "position" attribute affect the implied "last changed" date for a child entity when it was not actually changed
- P5: queries/pull (particularly recursive queries) can become difficult when connecting through wrapper entities

For my tree use-case, I don't care about P2 and P1 is not a big problem because N is generally low

All this research hasn't helped me find clarity on which solution is best for my tree use case but I'm leaning towards S2. Naturally the least complexity is my goal but I suspect that all solutions will be complex.

**Question** : do you have any experience with this problem and what can you share that will help others in deciding? I'll add more R's, S's and P's above as they are pointed out. I (and many others) will really appreciate any feedback.

*A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682064/properties-on-datomic-ref-relationships) was asked a couple of years ago but not much happened there.*

Comment: Are you sure the link for S2 is the right one?

Comment: Agreed, that post is not explicit about the order requirement. I've added another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I've had good success for my requirement (ordered tree storage) by using [Datomic Linked List](http://github.com/dwhjames/datomic-linklist) wrapper with a zipper. The linked list code has a couple of bugs which I will fork/fix/deploy to clojars soon.

This solution is quite simple and has constant time for change operations so will perform well.

One challenge has been multiple ordered child relationships. The linked list code assumes one ordered list per entity and in my case, I need 1 list for tree children but more lists for other data. I've worked around this but it's something to consider if your requirement is similar.

I'll post further comments if other useful observations come up from this prototype.

Comment: A downside of using zipper/linkedlist is that you cannot use a recursive datalog query to read a full tree. This is not a big problem since d/pull is a cheap operation so invoking it once for each node is fast

Comment: Another update, using the Linked List approach with Datomic Cloud is not ideal since it assumes reads are cheap (true only for peers) so for Cloud I would avoid it and use the Datofu solution since that can be queried using Datalog which is a single network round-trip instead of N x d/pull

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your actual use case (and you might have several different ones within single DB simultaneously).

First, choose between `one-to-many` and `many-to-many` parent-child relationship:

- `one-to-many` means you can stick extra attribute right onto child entity, avoiding spending precious datoms on extra `:db/id`, `:my.domain/guid`, `:ordinal/ref` attributes, and on history size.
- `many-to-many` means you have to have separate entity to track ordering among the children.

At this point, you still might want to choose separate entity, to avoid messing up some `latest change date` stats/subscriptions on child entities, if you have any. Semantically, changed order of children means parent entity has changed, not the children ones.

Next, getting  `recursive pull patterns and queries` question out of the way. If you went with an `attribute on child` – you are good already.
If you went with `separate entity`, keep ordinal entities in a separate attribute on a parent entity:

```
{:foo/bars [{:db/id 4}
            {:db/id 2}]
 :foo/bars-order [{:db/id 9 :ordinal/idx 0 :ordinal/ref {:db/id 2}}
                  {:db/id 8 :ordinal/idx 1 :ordinal/ref {:db/id 4}}]}
```

Downside is: you need to keep both in sync to avoid orphan ordinals, or unaccounted children.

Finally, `linked list` vs. `position values` is more a matter of taste. However, `positional values` have larger `tx-data` footprint (e.g. inserting single element at position 0 of 10 elements list needs 10 extra datoms, touching every 10 elements on top of adding that new one).

I think, the only inferior-no-matter-what solution – is wrapping children (`parent-wrapper-child`), it takes away recursive pull patterns from you, and gets in the way in other ways.

Now back to your use case:
  `single-parent` + `recursive queries` = `idx` or `next` attribute on child.

Comment: Thanks Misha, you've pointed out two more problems which I've added to the original question for reference. I'm going to try out S3 using https://github.com/dwhjames/datomic-linklist to see how it works. Would still welcome more feedback, experience reports from others....

Comment: Thanks @clojuremostly, that's what I meant in the P1 description. If I go with :position as numbers, I'll do that but, I'm halfway through linked-lists and it seems to be working out. I'll update as I go. Still hoping to hear more folks chime in with experience reports so that the community can trust this as a balanced survey of what works.

Comment: Ooops, didn't read properly. Deleted the noise. Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 0):

There's a new solution to this problem as of new feature in Datomic of June 2019, described in my answer to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682064/properties-on-datomic-ref-relationships/61406767#61406767).

Comment: I did not check but I suppose reverse relation will not work in such case since VAET will not be available when value type is :db.type/tuple instead of :db.type/ref. https://docs.datomic.com/pro/query/indexes.html#VAET